# WiX setup Project can't be able to find the local resource file where it is declared

Tags: c#, wix, setup-project, wix3

I have been modifying some WiX script in my setup project. When I want to declare new string resource and modify existing, I was looking for the existing string resources used in project.

I was looking some elements like this.

`<Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.CustomizeDlgDescription)" />`

here **loc.CustomizeDlgDescription** this string I want to see in which file it was declared when I was searching for this text in the whole project level, I couldn't find in any file I couldn't locate the declaration to modify.

I am relatively very new to WiX scripts and setup projects.

When I googled about this I got to know .WXL and .WXI files it will be declared but, in that file, also I have verified the string resources I was looking for is not declared there, I was very curious where that string resources file will be located.
**!(loc.CustomizeDlgDescription)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the many strings that are built into WixUIExtension. You can see all at https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib.